# $("form") returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to get the id of the form but it says: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Anyone know how to fix this? By the way I am not allowed to select the form by its ID, I have to use $("form") or similar.

Thank you

```
<form id="test">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"/>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="button" />
</form>

</body>



<script>

$(function(){
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var form = $("form");
    console.log (form.id.value);
 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: your form id is `test` so `$('#test')` should return the form.
To be clear, i say that because if you will have multiple forms, you will have to specify which on you refer to.

Answer (score 3):

`$("form")` returns a **jQuery object** which does not have an `id` property. Therefore, `$("form").id` returns `undefined`, and calling `.value` on that will result in an error.

Try the following instead:

```
$("form").attr("id")
```

The [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) jQuery function returns the value of the specified attribute — in this case `id`.

Comment: Thanks. And to select the input of this form?

Comment: To select any element by ID, use this: `$("#id-comes-here")`

Comment: What I mean is, can I do something like this:  var emailField = $("form").input[name="email"];

Comment: `var emailField = $("#email")`  -  it's as simple as that.

Comment: Or, if you want to search by the `name` attribute and not the `id`: `var emailField = $("input[name=email]")`